# How to disable keydown processing when using autocomplete with FF (or IE) in a text box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, autocomplete, onkeydown

In order to control what fields the Enter key affects, I wrote the folowing javascript which gets called on the keydown event:

```
function editorEnter(e)
{
    var key;
    if (window.event) key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
    else key = e.which;                               //firefox
    if (key == 13) addEditorRow('EditorTable');
}
```

Here's how it is used in the context of a text field:

```
<input type="text" name="EditorSurname" class="EditorSurnameText" 
 value="" onkeydown="editorEnter(event);" onkeyup="EnableSave();"/>
```

The problem is that in FireFox with autocomplete enabled, if I select a value from the autocomplete dropdown and press enter, it does not perform the autocomplete and adds the row to the table.  Is there a way to disbale the enter key functionality when selecting autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this related question: [Trap the enter key, but not when choosing the browser's autocomplete suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648993/trap-the-enter-key-but-not-when-choosing-the-browsers-autocomplete-suggestion)